# How can I passing another data from controller function to display result from another function in same view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

**Example function to load view :**

```
function ringkas(){
        $data['artikel_uji']=$this->db->get('tb_artikel_uji')->result();
        $this->load->view('v_header');
        $this->load->view('v_data_uji',$data);      
    }
```

After I load this view..I fill form in this view and click submit.
**Example view like this :**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>/c_index/hitung_knn" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fill_your_name">
<input type="submit" name="process">
</form>
```

after that, the result after I submit I want to display in this view too..so I call `function ringkas()` again. but how can I display the result from function hitung_knn?

**Example output from** `function hitung_knn()` :

```
function hitung_knn($id){
   $example= array('1','2','3','4','5');         
}
```

Comment: Try to call `ringkas()` inside `hitung_knn()`. Just code `$this->ringkas()` inside it.

Comment: But how can I get value from `hitung_knn()` in the view?@Ukasyah

Answer (score 1):

You might change to this:

```
function ringkas( $example = array() ){
    $data['artikel_uji']=$this->db->get('tb_artikel_uji')->result();
    $data['example']=$example;
    $this->load->view('v_header');
    $this->load->view('v_data_uji',$data);      
}



function hitung_knn($id){
   $example= array('1','2','3','4','5');         
   $this->ringkas($example);
}
```

Comment: Ya, sama-sama, gan.

Comment: Sama2 dari indo..,ok gan. Lol @Ukasyah

Answer (score 1):

```
function ringkas(){
    if($_POST){
        /* pass either as post parameter or just argument of function like ringkas($id=0)*/
        $this->input->post('id');
        $data['something'] = $this->hitung_knn($id);
    }else{
        $data['artikel_uji']=$this->db->get('tb_artikel_uji')->result();

    }
    $this->load->view('v_header');
    $this->load->view('v_data_uji',$data);  
}

function hitung_knn($id){
    return array('1','2','3','4','5');         
}

<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>/c_index/ringkas" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fill_your_name">
    <input type="submit" name="process">
</form>
```

Make sure this is not the perfect code but you will get the idea from it. You just need to call function hitung_knn fromk inside ringkas. And change your form post url to ringkas.